# How to implement a singleton // configure a module using browserify

Tags: browserify

My application consists of multiple script files on the front end. Each such file is in need of a module:

```
//foo.js
var myModule = require('../module/myMod');

//bar.js
var myModule = require('../module/myMod');
```

I am using browserify to get this to work.

Now I would like to configure my module at a central point

```
//aCentralPoint.js
var myModule = require('../module/myMod');

myModule.configure(//...);

//foo.js
var myModule = require('../module/myMod');

/**
*  I would expect this to be what I set in aCentralPoint.js
*/
console.log(myModule.config);
```

Unfortunately, due to the fact that `myModule` will be freshly injected into each file requiring it, this is unpossible.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The `require` function will always return the same instance of the module.

If in `module.js` you have:

```javascript
module.exports = {name: 'my object'};
```

Then in `foo.js`:

```javascript
require('./module').foo = 'hello from foo';
```

If you require it **later** in `bar.js`:

```javascript
console.log(require('./module')); //prints {name: 'my object', foo: 'hello from foo'}
```

Set up a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7nD8WaaJnQlVOexwUcaD?p=info)

Comment: I honestly can't reproduce this. Would you mind to set up a small plunker?

Comment: Added the plunker. In case that doesn't work, how are you running browserify? Also, try just running `node index.js` and see if that works.

Comment: Currently, this approach is not working for Browserify. It seems like Browserify stores an inmutable copy of the object, instead of a reference. Nevertheless, requireJS works as I would expect and I can modify the module in execution time.